# How can I detect when a mobile browser returns to a page that has been paused?

Tags: javascript, mobile, signalr

When a browser loses focus on a mobile device, typically the device stops JavaScript execution for the loaded page, but keeps the page.

When a user later returns to the page the browser shows the page it had previously loaded.

When using SignalR, an active browser can accept push messages from the server, and when the mobile device is running the JavaScript this works wonderfully, however, when the page is paused (due to the browser becoming inactive) the push notification are no longer received for that page.

This means that when I return to a page that has been inactive, it is out of date. It has missed some notifications from the server.

Given that the messages from the server are non-contiguous and could contain all manner of update data, it seems the best approach would be to force a refresh of the page when the browser is reactivated.

How can I detect the reactivation of the page in order to trigger a refresh?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with SignalR, but I would expect any JS client to have a callback method for a ["reconnect" event](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client#connectionreconnected-handler-). That's where you'd want to force a refresh. This way, it would also refresh all the data whenever the mobile client loses and regains connection.

If a reconnect event is not an option, you can try using the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) to determine when the tab regains visibility and force a refresh then.

Try this ([Fiddle link for mobile](https://jsfiddle.net/qd4fjt4L/2/)):

```js
function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (document.hidden) {
    logMessage('Document hidden.');
  } else {
    logMessage('Document visible. Trigger refresh.');
  }
}

function logMessage(message) {
  var d = new Date();
  var timestamp = d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds();
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerText = timestamp + ' - ' + message;
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange);

logMessage('Document is ' + document.visibilityState + '. Try minimizing the browser or changing tabs.');
```

Comment: These are both good ideas. I'm already using the reconnect for the SignalR but in this particular case with the mobile browser the event isn't triggered (even though the browser does connect) - It might be doing connect rather than the reconnect but this will be recursive if I refresh on connect. Option B of refreshing on page visibility is rather heavy handed and causes page refreshes when switching tab (on desktop and mobile) in many cases where the browser has not been paused which results in a choppy user experience which isn't ideal.

Comment: If you use SignalR's stateChanged event, you should be able to see what's happening to the connection when the mobile browser is minimized and restored. Is it firing the connect event again?